# Converting Java CompletableFuture to a Scala Future

Tags: scala, future

From my Scala function, I'm calling a Java API method that returns me a CompletableFuture. I would now need to convert this to a Scala Future! I guess I could use the scala java8 compact tool to get this job done, but which version of this tool should I use? I tried using:

`"org.scala-lang.modules" % "scala-java8-compat" % "0.9.0"`

My sbt build failed with

```
org.scala-lang.modules#scala-java8-compat;0.9.0: not found. I guess I should add a resolver, but which one?
```

Second, in order to use the FutureConverters.toScala, I need to get access to completionStage. From where can I get this?

For example., in the call:

```
scala.compat.java8.FutureConverters.toScala(completionStage)
```

From where do I get this CompletionStage?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
libraryDependencies += "org.scala-lang.modules" %% "scala-java8-compat" % "0.9.0"
```

which is the same as

```
libraryDependencies += "org.scala-lang.modules" % "scala-java8-compat_2.12" % "0.9.0"
```

Pay attention to `%%` or `_2.12`.

`CompletionStage` is a supertype of `java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture`.
So if you have a `CompletableFuture` that's it.